# Поменять 1 и 3 элемент стека местами через указатели

Tags: c++, visual-c++, стек

Доброго времени суток! Есть задача поменять 1 (вершину) и 3 элементы стека местами используя указатели. Я сделал, но используя 4 дополнительных переменных, а надо использовать 2 или 1. 
P.S. Код написан в Visual Studio, С++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

struct Stack 
{
    int info;
    Stack * next;
};

Stack* InStack(Stack *_begin, int in) 
{
    Stack *t = new Stack;
    t->info = in;
    t->next = _begin;
    return t;
}

Stack* exchange(Stack *_begin, int n)
{   
    Stack *p, *t, *c, *e;
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        cout << "Not enough elements!"<<endl;
        return _begin;
    }
    e = _begin;
    p = _begin->next;
    t = _begin->next->next;
    c = _begin->next->next->next;
    _begin = t;
    t->next = p;
    p->next = e;
    e->next = c;
  return _begin;
}

void View (Stack *p) {
    Stack *t = p;
    if (p == NULL) 
    {        
        cout << "Stack is empty!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "Stack: "<<endl;
    while (t != NULL) 
    {
        cout << t->info << endl;
        t = t->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Stack *_begin=NULL, *start=NULL, *t;
    int in,n;
    cout << "Input stack size: ";
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        in = rand()%40-20;
        _begin = InStack(_begin,in);
    }
    View (_begin);
    _begin=exchange(_begin, n);
    View (_begin);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поправте форматирование. А что значит предисловие в заголовке?

Comment: думаю, автор решил, что если такое написать, то все автоматом будут подписаны на его вопрос и объязательно ответят.

Comment: Ааа, а то я понял несколько иначе - если ты ботан не в теме, ступай дальше, здесь умные люди общяются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я перепишу только тело функции **exchange()**, ведь вопрос заключается именно в ее реализации.

```
Stack* exchange(Stack *_begin, int n)
{   
    Stack *new_begin, *forthElem;
    if (n <= 2)
    {
        cout << "Not enough elements!"<<endl;
        return _begin;
    }

    //начало изменений
    new_begin = _begin->next->next;
    forthElem = new_begin->next;

    new_begin->next = _begin->next;
    new_begin->next->next = _begin;
    _begin->next = forthElem;

    return new_begin;
}
```

Comment: А где у вас `begin` объявлено?

Comment: @0xdb , спасибо, это _begin. Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Ещё один остался.

Comment: Исправлено, спасибо